# Multi Operating System DBMS

Tags: database

I am creating a db for my family to use. We use both win & Linux on our network (cannot get her to completely get rid of win yet). What would be a good DBMS to use & create the db with?

edit: I am wanting to improve my db skills in the 3 db classes I had a few yrs ago, 2 ms accsess & 1 sql server. I have been creating tables on paper to make sure I get the relationships right. I was wanting to make it fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can specify your question:

- What do you want to do with the database?
- Do you only have one database on a home server / web server or a single instance on each computer?
- How much data must the database be able to hold?

I think you can use SQLite or MySQL, depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on what is your requirement. Do you need simple database with basic UI that people can use right away or full feature database.

For basic stuff you can use [LibreOffice's Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/base/), which is like MS Access.
Next up you can use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/), and for more features you can use [MySQL](http://mysql.com) or [PostGreSQL](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=postgresql&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.postgresql.org/&ei=-jUnT5nVNIO0rAfUnN3jAQ&usg=AFQjCNHhuOZnVQteX8H9LuxN9CJBVzl4ZA).